# In JavaScript terms how do you name this kind of object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JS terminology how do you name this kind of object:

```
var a = {"a":"wohoo", 2:"hello2", "d":"hello"};
```

I believe it is not an array as 'length' property is undefined on it.

Then what is it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a normal object.

The initializer is called an object literal.

Comment: But why do you use double quotes for property names? Is it a must? or it gives a different meaning?

Comment: @pencil: It's optional, although it's required if the names aren't valid identifiers.  In JSON, it's always required.

Comment: Actually I have seen this piece of line here as a Dictionary implementation in JS: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594850/is-there-a-dictionary-implementation-in-javascript

Comment: @pencil: Yes; that's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an object, i.e. an instance of `Object`. Same as doing:

```
var a = new Object();
a.a = "wohoo";
a["2"] = "hello2";
a.d = "hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an object.

In Chrome:

```
>> ({"0": 1}).toString()
"[object Object"]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Mozilla, it is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Object_Literals):

> An object literal is a list of zero or more pairs of property names and associated values of an object, enclosed in curly braces ({}). You should not use an object literal at the beginning of a statement. This will lead to an error or not behave as you expect, because the { will be interpreted as the beginning of a block.

Answer (score 0):

It is an object (and it work like a hash).

You could go to http://javascript.crockford.com/ for more deep info on javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Its called as a **literal notation**.  Its very powerful stuff dear and has almost replaced old XML in the field. In below example two notations are used both are having same purpose.

> var userObject = {
>       name : 'user1',
>       age: 24,
>       run:function(destination){
>           //make the man run
>       } };
>
> var userObject = {}; userObject.name =
>   "user1"; userObject.age = 24;
>   userObject.run =
>   function(destination){
>        //make this man to run };

So now out there its new hot topic whether AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript & XML) to AJ (Asynchronous JavaScript). Jokes apart its new stuff called as **JSON**. check below stuff for better understanding this thing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx