# Whats the fastest way to check if a string exists in a string collection in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, complexity-theory

In JavaScript, I need some data structure that can hold strings, and has a fast way to search if a string exists in it, and to insert a string in it.

I was planning to use an array, but I am currently using a dictionary where the key is the string and the value is just 'true' even through I don't use it.

I went with dictionary because I would think it would be something like an `AVL` tree, where the insert, delete and add are all `O(log(n))` time. And the array would have an insert, delete, and search of `O(n)` time.

Is this right, or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: If you use an array, you could use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Javascript doesn't have dictionaries, do you mean object?

Comment: Why don't you use a hash table?

Comment: kalley: isn't that still a linear search?; Barmar: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594850/is-there-a-dictionary-implementation-in-javascript; Dany Caissy: can you show me an example?

Comment: @Barmar: You can use an object *as* a dictionary.

Comment: @FelixKling Anything he does with this is using it _as_ a dictionary. His question was what built-in data type he should use, and then he referred to dictionary as if it were one.

Comment: @sneaky The answer in that question uses an object. Javascript doesn't have anything we _call_ a dictionary, but its objects are like Python dictionaries, Perl hashes, PHP associative arrays, and C++ maps.

Comment: There are only two data structures, arrays and objects (whereas arrays are objects too, but you'd process them a bit differently). Which one of those is faster you can find out with http://jsperf.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object.

Add string:

```
obj[string] = true;
```

Check if string exists:

```
obj.hasOwnProperty(string);
// or simply
obj[string]
```

Comment: Actually, using `obj[string]` to test the existence is a lot faster: http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in/2. I assume browsers optimize property access a lot.

Comment: @FelixKling Doesn't that signal an error if the property doesn't exist? I didn't want to recommend something that signals, although I notice lots of code like that in libraries like jQuery.

Comment: I think if it doesn't exist, it will be `undefined` or `null`, which you can check for.

Comment: If the property doesn't exist you get `undefined` which is falsy. So `if (obj[string])` will work fine in this case.

Comment: @FelixKling this is true and faster, but it also needs to be noted that `({})['valueOf']`, `({})['toString']`, [**etc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype#Properties) are not _undefined_.

Comment: I know that's what it returns, but I thought it also results in an error along the way, but the error is ignored by default.

Comment: Nope, no error. @PaulS: True, it depends on the use case. But if you know what kind of values you may get, then you can optimize for it :) In the worst case you can do `if (typeof obj[string] === 'boolean')` which is still a lot faster than `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: @FelixKling when I do these kinds of checks I explicity check for `true` or `1` to reduce this problem, e.g. `obj[key] = 1; if (obj[key] === 1) {/* found */}`

Comment: @PaulS.: Of course, that makes sense. Somehow I was thinking about a scenario were one has multiple different values (because that's why I made the test in the first case). But no need to make it more complicated than it is, comparing the value should be first choice here.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an array.

You can use **[indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)** to find the position. And **[splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)** to insert a string into array object. Also if position does not matter, use `push()`.

This should be fast enough, it is in `JS` library.

EDIT:

Both `indexOf()` and [**splice()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175925/whats-the-time-complexity-of-array-splice-in-google-chrome) are linear.

Comment: Using this, is really faster than a dictionary?

Comment: `indexOf` will still be a linear search, i.e. `O(n)`.

Comment: JS guys would not create this if it was not :)

Comment: Since order doesn't seem to matter, I would just use `.push` to add a value. Certainly faster than `.splice`. What makes you think it is `O(nlogn)`?

Answer (score 0):

var stringStore = {};

stringStore['sample-string-1'] = 'sample-string-1';

stringStore['sample-string-2'] = 'sample-string-2';

if (stringStore['sample-string-2'] ) 
  console.log("string 2 exists");
else
  console.log("string 2 doesn't exists");

if (stringStore['sample-string-3'] ) 
  console.log("string 3 exists");
else
  console.log("string3  doesn't exists");